# Page number digits do not look homogenous

Tags: koma-script, page-numbering, scrlayer-scrpage

Why in the following MWE, the numbers `0`, `1` and `2` look more small then the others?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

\RequirePackage[markcase=used]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\oldstylenums}
%\providepairofpagestyles{thesisSimple}{%
    \clearpairofpagestyles%
    \automark[chapter]{chapter} %\automark[right side]{left side}
    \ihead{\headmark}% Inner header
    \ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}% Outer header
    %-----------------
    \ohead*{} % added
    %\ofoot*{\pagemark}
    \cfoot*{\pagemark}  %Vall added, to have centered page number in the footer
    %----- fin ------
%}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Blabal}

\lipsum[1-78]

\end{document}
```

PS: the above code is from `MastersDoctoralThesis.cls` which I am using

Comment: Hehe, they are correct, compare the number sizes in `\oldstylenums{1234567890}`. If you  want something stable in the footer to compare the numbers against, try `\cfoot*{--\pagemark--}`

Comment: @daleif or better still, `\cfoot*{\textup{[}\pagemark\textup{]}}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how the old style numbers looks like in the default font (en-dash added for reference):

[image]

(`--\oldstylenums{1234567890}--`)

As you can see the sizes vary greatly, and without something stable it is hard to see that these are old style numerals.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that :). Can I remove it; i.e. use just `\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{}` ?

Comment: @LlavDem, here you can just out comment it, not sure how to go about it is that specific class, you'd probably gave to read the manual for that part